# Changing image src with javascript

Tags: javascript, image, switch-statement

I am attempting to change an image with a javascript function. I thought it was easy, but can't get it to work. I can't seem to find my error. Here is the javascript:

```
function rollDice() {
rollCount = rollCount + 1;
dice1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6));
switch (dice1) {
    case 0:
        document.getElementById("dice1").src = "Photos/redpipdice1.png";
        break;
    case 1:
        document.getElementById("dice1").src = "Photos/redpipdice2.png";
        break;
    case 2:
        document.getElementById("dice1").src = "Photos/redpipdice3.png";
        break;
    case 3:
        document.getElementById("dice1").src = "Photos/redpipdice4.png";
        break;
    case 4:
        document.getElementById("dice1").src = "Photos/redpipdice5.png";
        break;
    case 5:
        document.getElementById("dice1").src = "Photos/redpipdice6.png";
        break;
}
}
```

It is linked to the html with this:

```
        <div class = "dice-images inline">
        <img id = "dice1" src = "Photos/redpipdice1.png" />
        <p>Click dice to hold</p>
            <div class = "button">
                <button id = "roll-dice" type="button" onclick = "rollDice()">ROLL!</button>
            </div>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the browser's console? Note that you have an extra parenthesis in `Math.floor(Math.random() * 6));`. You also need a `var` with `rollCount`. That aside, as long as your image paths are correct it should work fine.

Comment: I would suggest using `rollCount++;` as apposed to `rollCount = rollCount + 1;`

Comment: @user3470353 `<button id = "roll-dice" type="button" onclick = "rollDice()">ROLL!</button>`

Comment: Thanks so much! That fixed it! I always miss some small detail like that. Nice to have a second pair of eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<img id="dice1" src="Photos/redpipdice1.png" />
<button id="roll-dice" type="button">ROLL!</button>
```

---

```
document.getElementById(`roll-dice`).addEventListener(`click`, () => {
    document.getElementById(`dice1`).src = `Photos/redpipdice${getRandomInt(1, 6)}.png`;
    rollCount++;
});

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return min + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you

Comment: Nice, as shown here, a set of one to one relationship within condition and consequences can be merged